# Passing PHP variables to the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

When a user signs up to my application (college project), they are asked for their address. I convert this address to latitude and longitude and then store it in my database.

I access the latitude and longitude like so:

```
<?php
    require '../connect.php';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM userinformation WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']. "'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $lat = $row["latitude"];
            $lng = $row["longitude"];
            echo $lat;
            echo $lng;

        }
    }
?>
```

I then try to pass the $lat and $lng variable into the Maps API script like so:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: '<?php echo $lat;?>', lng: '<?php echo $lng;?>'}
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: '<?php echo $lat;?>', lng: '<?php echo $lng;?>'}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}
```

This gives me the following page:

[image: PHP Page]

I have also tried converted the PHP variables to JS:

```
var js_variable  = '<?php echo $lat;?>';
document.write(js_variable);
var js_variable1  = '<?php echo $lng;?>';
document.write(js_variable1);
```

I then pass in the JS variables instead of the PHP variables, however the output is still the same. What would be the correct way to pass a variable as lat/lng instead of a hardcoded value:

```
center: {lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070}
position: {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067}
```

Comment: What does that PHP resolve to in the browser?  If it looks exactly like the "hardcoded values" you specify above, [it should just work](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y0bmbq4w/) (you probably don't want to use document write to create your "javascript" versions of the variables though)

Comment: @geocodezip In the browser I only get a blank Map canvas when I use variables containing the lat/lng however if I hardcode the values then I get a map.

Comment: If you view the source in the browser do the two versions (working/hardcoded vs. not working values from PHP) look the same?  (I would assume not).  Can you tell us what the difference is?

Comment: @geocodezip When I run the hardcoded values I get: position: {lat: 30.365273, lng: -81.699600} where as with the PHP escaping I get: position: {lat: '30.365273', lng: '-81.699600'}. So the '' are causing the issues but they are required to escape the PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replace the values in [the fiddle with strings `{lat: '30.365273', lng: '-81.699600'}`](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y0bmbq4w/1/), I get a javascript error reported by the API: `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`.

If I use `parseFloat` on those strings, it works:

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: parseFloat('30.365273'),
      lng: parseFloat('-81.699600')
    }
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {
      lat: parseFloat('30.365273'),
      lng: parseFloat('-81.699600')
    }
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

change your PHP to be:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: parseFloat('<?php echo $lat;?>'), lng: parseFloat('<?php echo $lng;?>')}
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: parseFloat('<?php echo $lat;?>'), lng: parseFloat('<?php echo $lng;?>')}
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}
```

Comment: At first I got a blank white screen. I then saw that you forgot parseFloat in position : for lng. However this still didn't fix the problem of the blank white screen and I really cannot see why since the snippet works and it works on Jsfiddle. Here is my file in it's entirety (although it's all posted here anyhow): https://gist.github.com/adhorrig/806e353c7a159bd6836d.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. I accidentally removed position:. Thanks a million! I was trying to solve this for five hours now. I'm curious why parseFloat fixed the issue though?

Comment: The API was rejecting the strings from PHP `'<?php echo $lat;?>'`; those _have_ to be numbers.  `parseFloat` takes a string representation of a floating point number and turns it into a number.

Answer (score 1):

I think having the PHP echo the value directly into your JavaScript is likely the problem. Try passing lat and lng as parameters to your map function instead.

```
function initMap(myLat, myLng) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong)
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong)
  });
  marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
}
```

Edit: try using the Google Maps function for setting latitude and longitude, as above.

Comment: Before var map I've tried declaring the variables like so : var myLat  = '<?php echo $lat;?>'; but this implementation just gives me a blank white screen opposed to the screenshot in the op

Comment: Two things you could try: declare the variables outside the scope of the function, or possibly try using the parseInt("str"); function to get an integer value of whatever php is being echo'd, e.g. var strLat = '<?php echo $lat; ?>', and var myLat = parseInt(strLat);

Comment: Hmm. I've tried both of these and still neither work. It's a tough one, I'm struggling to see *why* it's not working at this point.

Comment: Does the map render correctly when you pass hardcoded values?

Comment: Yes it does and the values in my db for coordinates are valid latitude / longitude.

Comment: Rereading my last comment I realized you should use parseDouble(strLat); not parseInt (silly me), as of course Latitude and Longitude values require decimal points. Does this change anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, it changed not. A blank screen was still the output instead of an empty map canvas from the OP.