# Local server side working, but not when hosted on gearhost

Tags: javascript, php

Previously, I posted this question:

[Passing PHP variables to the Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357874/passing-php-variables-to-the-google-maps-api)

The problem was essentially passing PHP variables containing latitude / longitude into the Maps Javascript API.

The full work code is below:

```
<script>
    var marker;

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: {lat: parseFloat('<?php echo $lat;?>'), lng: parseFloat('<?php echo $lng;?>')}
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: {lat: parseFloat('<?php echo $lat;?>'), lng: parseFloat('<?php echo $lng;?>')}
        });
            marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    }

    function toggleBounce() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }

</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

This works locally and I get expected results, the map showing the correct location.

However when I deployed the site to gearhost, the map canvas never loaded. Or I should say, never loads.

When I view the page source, the correct PHP variables are passed in and everything is correct.

What reason could be behind the map canvas not loading?

Comment: Is your API key limited to certain domains? For this, I'd recommend trying it without your API key at all, you shouldn't need it tat this point I think.

Comment: Check for JS errors. Create a fresh API key and try.

Comment: @LoganBentley When I remove the key and navigate to the page, I get the "API Key is not valid or can not be used on this domain" error, this error doesn't show up when I have my API key put in.

Comment: Hmm. Then I would recommend what Jaya said, check for JS errors - they'll give you the direction to debug it.

Comment: @LoganBentley The only JS error is "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery". Any other directions?

Comment: Is it a public page that I could take a look at?

Comment: Sounds like your JQuery is not loading. How are you linking to JQuery Source? Check your resulting code against JSLint.

Comment: @LoganBentley  , the problem was that I had my Jquery import after my bootstrap import. All working now.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it's all sorted.